# Azure Table Storage - Indexes?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a table of entities, "stories" for example. It will contain a large list of "stories" that people can vote on.

The main feature of my application will be users reading the "top" stories, which have the most votes (and might eventually have other algorithms going on).

My first thought for the structure of the Azure table is:

- RowKey = unique id
- PartitionKey = ??? (maybe User Id, because you can view a User's list of stories)
- Title
- Description
- User Id
- Url

How can I effectively query against stories considered the "top" stories? Most of the traffic is going to be querying the top stories, and doesn't need to pull out ranges of stories otherwise. What I'm wanting is a way to index the top stories, but indexes are not a feature of table storage. I thought about keeping a second table, but that could get hairy if the user updates the story in the other table.

This is my first hangup using Azure Table Storage, the rest of the app is going to work great. I'd hate to upgrade to using full SQL Azure because of this one issue.

PS - I'm open to storing the "top" stories in another place besides an Azure table if it makes sense. My server will be running C# web api, but probably makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Table storage is a flat, non-relational data store. As such, the way you store and model data is dramatically different. A common pattern is modelling two different data-stores for different types of access. So one table for most recent, and another that's update for say "most liked".

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking having two tables is the way to go. As people vote up a story, I can check the vote count copy the record over to the "top" stories table. If I have a commments table, they can be accessed by the storie's "id", and I think this will work fine if the "top" stories table has a copy of the records.

Comment: Is it better to use two partitions, or two tables? Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't much matter as the partition is the scale unit and Azure Table storage is schema less. The bigger question you need to think of is how to manage the "voting up". If you have thousands of folks hitting an article, the voting table can be bottlenecked. Maybe check out: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-43-Scalable-Counters-with-Windows-Azure

Answer (score 8):

The [Azure Storage Table Design Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) walks you through different approaches for creating your own secondary indicies. It also provides principles to considering when designing NoSQL databases and implementation guidance.

Comment: This is good info, others might want to know @Jason is the author. I don't think he needed a -1, though, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You should first reflect what "top stories" really means.
Do you mean last top 10 stories or rather above specyfic rate value?

You could use rate value as partition key (eg Rate_1, Rate_2, Rate_3, Rate_4, Rate_5).
But you have to round values to integers so if the value is 4.1 it will be placed into partition Rate_4.

Alternatively you can use just 2 partitions: "TopStories" and "OtherStories".

Comment: So what mechanism will move a story from a "top" story partition to the other partition? I will have to delete the record and insert a new one? This would happen as people vote a story up or down.

Comment: Is it better to use two partitions, or two tables? Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace entity. What data access patterns do you anticipate? If many updates then updating partition key might be not good solution. You can also provide caching top stories to improve preformace of reading.

Comment: Regarding your question "two partitions or two tables" answer is: two partitions. But there is not difference if you will use one or two tables in terms of scalability.

Comment: I suggest you to keep separate table for daily votes so that you can  aggregate multiple votes instead of recalculating rates for stories every time someone will vote. For example every day you will collect votes and use scheduled night batch update on stories table to recalculate rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Given that

1. your top story algorithm may evolve overtime
2. the fact that is summary like information
3. and can be aged out

I would stay way from table storage, and instead model it in a relational database for flexibility of querying.

Comment: There's scale issues with doing it in a RDBMS. 
1) doesn't impact the storage approach
2) can be addressed in Azure Table as well
3) can be addressed in Azure Table as well

Comment: My recommendation for using an SQL Db is only for tracking the "top stories", and not for the stories themselves. The top story algorithm may only need to track stories say in the last 24 hours and hence not need to work at large scale. A SQL Db definitely supports more versatile queries scenarios and would be my "top" choice.

Comment: Well, an SQL DB is the way we've all been trained, but the price is 100x greater.